# Calculating mathematical expressions in C using getchar()

Tags: c

I have been assigned with a school task. 
In this task I have to create a program in C language that reads as an input from the user a mathematical expression and returns the result of it. For example the input must be something like 30 + 400 and the output must be in this case the result of the addition of 30 and 400 which is 430.The program must calculate apart from the addition and the other mathematical operations(subtraction,multiplication,division).Each expression must be read in one line and also I am not allowed to use arrays or any other complex data structure in my code.
I have tried some methods to solve this task but i can't understand how to separate the numbers from the operators so the expression can be calculated.
Here is the i have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int ch,result;
    int plus;
    int minus;
    int mult; 
    int div;
    while((ch = getchar())!= EOF){
        plus = 0;
        minus = 0;
        mult = 0;
        div = 0;
        if (ch != '\n'){
            if (ch >= '0' && ch <='9'){ //Checks if the character is a number
                result += ch;
            }else if(ch== '+'){//Checks if the character is an operator
                plus =1;
            }else if(ch== '-'){
                minus = 1;
            }else if(ch == '*'){
                mult = 1;
            }else if(ch== '/'){
                div = 1;
            }

        }
        printf("%d\n",result); 
    }

}
```

Any suggestions or ideas would be very helpful.
P.S. I am sorry for my English and if I dint use the appropriate terms to describe this problem .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getchar` returns the `ASCII` value you need to convert it into decimal.

You can use two `integers` to store the inputted numbers and act on it.

**Example:**

```
int num1 = 0,num2 = 0;
char op;
int state = 0;
while((ch = getchar())!= EOF){

    if (ch != '\n'){
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <='9'){ //Checks if the character is a number
           if (state == 0) 
           num1 = num1*10 + ch- '0'; // Convert ASCII to decimal
           else 
           num2 = num2*10 + ch- '0'; // Convert ASCII to decimal
        }else {
        /* Operator detected now start reading in second number*/
        op = ch;
        state = 1;
       }
    }
    else {
       int result =0;
       switch(op)
       {
         case '+':
            result = num1 + num2;
         break;
         case '-':
            result = num1 - num2;
         break;
         case '*':
            result = num1 * num2;
         break;
         case '/':
            result = num1 / num2;
         break;
       }
      printf("%d\n",result); 
      num1 = 0;
      num2 = 0;
      state = 0;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me a lot.